# TextChanged Event not firing until focus changed from that textbox(telerik textbox)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Trying to tigger textchange event of textbox but it did not trigger until the user completed the input and shifted focus from that textbox to another.
Html Code:

```html
<telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="RadTextBox" Width="100%" 
                    OnTextChanged="RadTextBox_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    EnableViewState="false"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Vb.net code

```vb
Protected Sub RadTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadTextBox.TextChanged
    result = Session("mydt")
    Dim dv_ As DataView = result.DefaultView
    dv_ = New DataView(result, "abc like '%" & RadTextBox.Text & "%'", "id", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
    RadListBox.DataSource = dv_.ToTable
    RadListBox.DataTextField = "abc"
    RadListBox.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Please suggest

Comment: Can you try the OnKeyDown or the OnKeyUp events?

Comment: @PriyanPerera..cna you give me some example of that...i had never used these events

Comment: ["TextChanged server event, which is raised when ... the input loses focus"](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/textbox/server-side-programming/textchanged-event.html). You'll have to look at the [OnKeyPress](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/textbox/client-side-programming/events/onkeypress.html) event & ajax.

Comment: @Developer, looks like OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp is not available in Telerik, can you try the OnKeyPress as mentioned in the above comment? Try this link, https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/textbox/client-side-programming/events/onkeypress

Comment: @PriyanPerera..i tried this but what i am not getting is how to call the server side textbox textchange event on press of each key. It only works when focus changes from that textbox.

Comment: Server side code is basically a post back what you want to do is client side JQuery that will call a server side function that returns the new list then assign it to your control via JQuery.

Comment: @EJD...yes you are right.. I had achieved that using javascript because on each key press i cant do the page load.